# How to group and sum all currencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I hope the title is correct. I need to sum all currencies ie all of $, £ etc, but not to combine all into one sum.

Basically if I have 2x `$4` and 3x `£10`, that will be `$8` and `£30`

I have an `Income` model with attributes `:currency` (string) and `:amount` (float):

What I have works but I feel it can refactor a bit:

```
Income.all.group(:currency).count.map do |k,v|
  Income.where(currency: k).map.sum(&:amount)
end
```

That gives me an array of the total. Ok-ish. I needed a more nicer format such as an Hash:

```
{
  USD => 8.0,
  GBP => 30.0
}
```

Possible? How, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following would do:

```
Income.group(:currency).sum(:amount)
```

The SQL would looks like:

```
SELECT SUM(income.amount) AS sum_amount, currency AS currency
  FROM income
  GROUP BY income.currency
```

Comment: OMG! That simple? Thanks